# Bash: Multiple pattern matching

Tags: bash, scripting, pattern-matching

I use this script to convert all the `.png` files in a directory to `.jpg` files. If I want to convert not just png files, but also tif, gif and bmp files into jpg, how this script can be modified?

```
  #!/bin/bash
    for f in *.png ; do
        convert "$f" -resize 50% "${f%.*}.jpg"
    done
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add the exensions you want to process; for example:

```
for f in *.png *.tif *.gif; do
```

or just:

```
for f in *.{png,tif,gif}; do
```

another approach could be: *find every image file in a directory or a tree of folders and convert them to jpg except if the image is already a jpg file*; for example (not tested):

```
find . -exec bash -c 'file "$1" | grep "image data" | grep -iv JPEG && convert "$1" -resize 50% "${1%.*}.jpg"' {} {} \;
```

Comment: Is there a way to suppress f being '*png' if there are no png files to be found?  for i in *jpg *png; do echo $i; done in a directory with all jpegs produces a *png in addition to the expected output.

Comment: Found it: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56051/avoiding-errors-due-to-unexpanded-asterisk/56053#56053   for i in *jpg *png; do [ -e "$i" ] || [ -L "$i" ] || continue; echo $i; done

Answer (score 1):

`for f in *.{png,tif,gif,bmp}; do`